# classes and templates companion types

Tags: c++, types, type-members

I'm learning C++ and every now and then I bump into something like "companion types" or some "machine dependent integral type" that is used on different occasions, such as:

```
vector<int>::size_type
```

or

```
std::size_t
```

or lately I was reading about IO types and objects and I read about a type that is "defined by IO classes" such as:

```
istream::iostate
```

that apparently is an integral type used by some kind of bit-patterns used to indicate the state of a stream object.

I know that classes can include (besides member functions and data members) type members, in the form of type alias declarations (`typedef` and `using` alias declaration), but it doesn't make sense to me completely, there must be something I haven't read about yet.
Can you please explain?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Which part doesn't make sense to you?

Comment: @Barry  I can't understand what "a class defines a companion type".What does it mean? how can a class define a machine dependent integral type beyond those built-in in the language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the standard doesn't specify the exact type of something, but rather only it's behavior, it is up to the implementation to decide how they want to handle it.

For example, say that the standard says that there must be a class `Foo` that also has a `foo_t`. This `foo_t` is required to be able to represent some range of integral values, but it doesn't say that they must be fixed size (like [`std::int32_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)). In my implementation, I could just say

```
class Foo
{
public:
    using foo_t = long;
};
```

Then the users of this class would not need to know the internals that `foo_t` is actually a `long` under the hood, nor should they depend on that being true for all compilers (as others may choose to implement it differently). They simply know that `foo_t` is capable of holding some range of integral values, based on whatever the C++ standard says it should.

```
int main()
{
    Foo::foo_t x = 10;
    std::cout << x;
}
```

Comment: so they're just public type members,which are nothing more than just type aliases of built-in types?

Comment: Basically yes, though they don't need to be an alias of a built-in type / primitive, they could be an alias of another class for example. Maybe I have a `Bar` class that I defined that is a custom representation of integral values that I made for some reason, I could just as well say `using foo_t = Bar;`

Comment: @Luca Generally, yes (e.g. for `size_type`). For `iostate`, doesn't have to be a built-in type. The standard allows it to potentially be an enum or a `bitset` (or an integer).

Comment: @Luca in short, they are here to: abstract irrelevant implementation details and make the code more readable/understandable (it's easier to understand a code with `index_t`, `label_t`, `size_t` than a code with only `unsigned long` instead for instance)

Comment: generally speaking,they're type aliases used to abstract away implementation regarding how a type is defined? so,they're basically type aliases and they do not define new types (coming from Java I'm thinking inner classes here..)